# LARAVEL: Hacer una consulta con un where que vaya de cierto año a cierto año

Tags: php, html, laravel

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta en laravel (de php) en mi controller pero no se bien como hacerlo, necesito filtrar de una tabla de mi base de datos los datos en un inervalo de tiempo (2019 al 2010 por ejemplo).

````
    ```$datos = DB::table('main')
        ->join('academico', 'main.id', '=', 'academico.id_cliente')
        ->select('main.Nombre', 'main.Apellido', 'main.id', 'main.Email' 'academico.*')
        ->where('academico.ciclo', '>=', '2019') // aqui no sabria que poner en el where para que me filtre datos desde el 2019 al 2010
        ->GroupBy('main.id')

        ->get();```
````

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar `where` con un arreglo:

```
$datos = DB::table('main')
 ->join('academico', 'main.id', '=', 'academico.id_cliente')
 ->select('main.Nombre', 'main.Apellido', 'main.id', 'main.Email' 'academico.*')
 ->where('academico.ciclo', '>=', '2010')
 ->where([
    ['academico.ciclo', '>=', '2010'],
    ['academico.ciclo', '<=', '2019'],
  ])
 ->GroupBy('main.id')
 ->get();
```

O algo más simple, utilizar 2 `where`:

```
$datos = DB::table('main')
 ->join('academico', 'main.id', '=', 'academico.id_cliente')
 ->select('main.Nombre', 'main.Apellido', 'main.id', 'main.Email' 'academico.*')
 ->where('academico.ciclo', '>=', '2010')
 ->where('academico.ciclo', '<=', '2019')
 ->GroupBy('main.id')
 ->get();
```